# FFMEG option scale=-1 and scale=-2

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to convert a video and resize it with scale=-1:720, but got the error "width not divisible by 2". And I solved it with: scale=-2:720.
What are the differences between

```
scale=-1:720
```

and

```
scale=-2:720
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **-2** instead of **-1** if you want the error message to go away. It will automatically adjust the **-2** dimension to be divisible by 2.

The reason why you get the error message when you use **-1** is because you're telling ffmpeg to keep the same aspect ratio as the original. When it cannot it returns with the error message "not divisible by 2". Lets say you have a input video of 1080x1920 and you use the command `-vf scale=-1:360` to resizing it to a height of 360, you will end up with a width of 202.5 pixels. That is why you're getting the error message "width not divisible by 2".

How-ever by using **-2** it tells ffmpeg **(!if need be!)** to adjust the **-2** dimension to be divisible by 2. In the case above, it will round the width down to 202 pixels but the output will have a slightly different aspect ratio to the original.

Even though the error message is annoying I do believe it is the correct thing to do. Report a error to the user and let them choose the best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

It's in [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1):

> If one and only one of the values is -n with n >= 1, the scale filter will use a value that maintains the aspect ratio of the input image, calculated from the other specified dimension. After that it will, however, make sure that the calculated dimension is divisible by n and adjust the value if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about `-1` and `-2` like about `-n` then this sets the specified dimension (width, height) to be a multiple of `n`.